# showing duplicated images from previous tableview cell when using ImageSlideshow pod

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uitableview

this my response which media is the images I want to show in slideshow view horizontally in tableview :

---

```
media": [
                    {
                        "id": 555,
                        "postId": 274,
                        "media": "https://onebusinessqrcode.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/b885b600-2d2c-5d84-aa64-259e946763e9.png",
                        "createdAt": "2021-05-22T04:01:03.351Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-05-22T04:01:03.351Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 554,
                        "postId": 274,
                        "media": "https://onebusinessqrcode.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/81a71835-1808-5d16-b9ff-062a345a9612.png",
                        "createdAt": "2021-05-22T04:01:03.154Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-05-22T04:01:03.154Z"
                    }
                ]
```

---

but suddenly I found that I got repeated images like this in the view in the same tableview row and I don't have all this pics for one cell you understand it may be from reusable cell !! may be from array I got the images from repeated it suddenly !!:

### number of images in the cell increasing when scrolling

[image: see the image]
I don't know why this is my code may will help you

---

```
// arr to store all images I got from server to show them
var postImages = [SDWebImageSource]()
```

---

### in cellForRowAt for tableView:

```
    //Configure the cell...
    let postText = ArraysModel.posts[indexPath.row]
    if let pictureString = postText.media {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PicCell", for: indexPath) as! PicCell
        
        cell.postTextLabel.text = postText.postText

        
        for image in pictureString {
            let sources = SDWebImageSource(urlString: image.media  ?? "")
            if let sdImages = sources {
                postImages.append(sdImages)
            }
        }

            cell.slideShowImage.setImageInputs(postImages)
            cell.slideShowImage.contentScaleMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
            cell.slideShowImage.activityIndicator = DefaultActivityIndicator()
            cell.slideShowImage.delegate = self

            return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You May add this in your PicCell class

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.slideShowImage.setImageInputs([])
    self.postImages.removeAll()
}
```

And change you tableview delegate method like this

```
let postText = ArraysModel.posts[indexPath.row]
if let pictureString = postText.media {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PicCell", for: indexPath) as! PicCell
    cell.postTextLabel.text = postText.postText
    cell.prepareForReuse()
    for image in pictureString {
        let sources = SDWebImageSource(urlString: image.media  ?? "")
        if let sdImages = sources {
            postImages.append(sdImages)
        }
    }
    cell.slideShowImage.setImageInputs(postImages)
    cell.slideShowImage.contentScaleMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    cell.slideShowImage.activityIndicator = DefaultActivityIndicator()
    cell.slideShowImage.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

Comment: thank you solved you really helped me bro ^^
can you give me explaination about prepare froReuse and why I removed items from the array

Comment: If a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is, it has a reuse identifier—this method is invoked just before the object is returned from the UITableView method dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:). For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state. The table view's delegate in tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) should always reset all content when reusing a cell. If the cell object does not have an associated reuse identifier, this method is not called.

Comment: If you override this method, you must be sure to invoke the superclass implementation.